# How can I prevent the text from truncating when different tabs are clicked in succession?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a type writer effect, that responds to the click of the tab.  Once the tab is clicked the content box changes and begins the typing effect and the corresponding tab changes as well.  However if I were to click on a tab, say tab 1 then tab 2, then back to tab 1 in rapid succession or even moderate succession, the text of the content box ends abruptly and the type effect doesn't print out all the text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#tab-wrapper div.myTabs').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('div.content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
        typeWriterEffect(tab_id, document.getElementById(tab_id).innerHTML, 50);
    });
});

var timer;

function typeWriterEffect(id, sentence, speed) {
    var index = 0; //reset index
    clearInterval(timer); //clear old timer
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ""; //clear it immediately to prevent flicker on click
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        var char = sentence.charAt(index);
        if (char === '<') index = sentence.indexOf('>', index);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = sentence.substr(0, index);
        index++;
        if (index === sentence.length) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, speed);
}
```

I figured I could store the innerHTML text into the data() method, but that didn't seem to work or maybe I did it wrong, same results.

So anyway, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7V4NA/30/) of everything I just talked about.

Comment: That maybe because you clear the global timer every time typeWriterEffect() is called. Try to use it as a local variable, declared inside the function.

Comment: The reason I made the timer variable global is to prevent flickering otherwise.  Flickering for some reason occurs when I make it local.  I know eventually I will have to address that, since globals are not good programming practice.

Comment: It's not only bad programming practive, it is probably the source of your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

That maybe because you clear the global timer every time typeWriterEffect() is called. Try to use it as a local variable, declared inside the funtion.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#tab-wrapper div.myTabs').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('div.content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
        typeWriterEffect(tab_id, document.getElementById(tab_id).innerHTML, 50);
    });
});
var timer;
function typeWriterEffect(id, sentence, speed) {
    var self = this;
    var index = 0; //reset index
    self.timer = setInterval(function () {
        var char = sentence.charAt(index);
        if (char === '<') index = sentence.indexOf('>', index);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = sentence.substr(0, index);
        index++;
        if (index === sentence.length) {
            clearInterval(self.timer);
        }
    }, speed);
    clearInterval(self.timer); //clear old timer
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ""; //clear it immediately to prevent flicker on click
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7V4NA/34/